# What is the difference between opposite and against?

Tags: prepositions

> When pushed, this push switch generates a reaction force opposite (opposing) / against a force applied to it, protecting it from an excessive applied force.

I would like to know which of "opposite / opposing" and "against" is suitable for the sentence above I created.  As far as I searched, it seems that "against" is usually used in combination with real objects, such as walls and wind.

Answer (score 1):

In the sample sentence, both are valid terms. They both express the fact that the reaction force is contra to the force applied.

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

> When pushed, this push switch generates a reaction force **opposing *the* force** applied to it, protecting it from an excessive applied force.

A *force* is more of an abstraction than a physical object. So I would use *opposing*. And I would use *the*, since it is specifically the result of the "push" already mentioned.

Comment: As @Tᴚoɯɐuo mentioned, this phrase could stand some rephrasing (too many words to get the meaning across, and you used "force" three times).

Answer (score 0):

The dictionaries present the two words as write similar, without making a distinction.

From my point of view, the difference between them is the active / passive kind of action which they describe:

- **opposite / oppose** - is more passive; e.g. a wall is opposing the force applied to it; the wall does not make an effort, it just refuses to comply;
- **against** - is a more active active attitude; e.g. people protest against (something); they use energy trying to cancel something they do not agree with.

When we speak about forces, either of opposite / against is (usually) OK, as the reference word (force) already makes clear that use of energy is involved.